# DocuSign API - Retrieve Authorize.Net Transaction ID for Payment

Tags: docusignapi

When you view a completed envelope with a Payment via the DocuSign web site you can see the Authorize.Net Transaction ID under the list of Recipients:

[image]

Is it possible to use the DocuSign REST API to retrieve the value for the Authorize.Net Transaction ID that appears here? I have been retrieving the Envelope via the API but don't see this data in any of the responses so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve this by calling GET recipient tabs API endpoint for the signer [link](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipienttabs/list/).

You should be able to see it under formulaTabs - paymentDetails - chargeId, in the response body